# Memory leaks in socket server PHP

Tags: php, sockets, memory-leaks

```
Class ServerSocket {

    protected $IP_ADDRESS = IP_ADDRESS; 
    protected $PORT = PORT_NUMBER; 
    protected $userClass = 'WebSocketUser'; 
    protected $mysock;
    protected $users = array();
    public static $sockets = array();
    public $clients = array();
    protected $countSockets = 0;
    protected $socketsLimit = 1000;

    FUNCTION __construct()
    {
        $this->mysock = socket_create(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, SOL_TCP);
        socket_bind($this->mysock, $this->IP_ADDRESS, $this->PORT);
        socket_listen($this->mysock, 4096);
        self::$sockets[] = $this->mysock;
    }


    /**
    * Main function
     * 
    */
    FUNCTION runServer()
    {
        $sock_id = 0;
        $client_id = 0;

        while ( true )
        {
            if ( empty(self::$sockets) )
            {
                self::$sockets[$sock_id] = $this->mysock;
                $sock_id++;
            }

            $read = self::$sockets;
            $write = $except = null;

            foreach ( $read as $socket )
            {
                if ( $socket == $this->mysock )
                {
                    //Accepting new clients
                    while ( ($client = socket_accept($socket) ) )
                    {
                        foreach ( $this->clients as $key=>$clientThread )
                        {
                            echo 'Thread is closed : '.$clientThread->getIsClosed() . "\n";

                            if($clientThread->getIsClosed() == 1 || $clientThread->isTerminated() || !$clientThread->isRunning())
                            {
                                unset($this->clients[$key]);
                                $clientThread->kill();
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                $responce = $clientThread->isThreadAlive();
                                if($clientThread->getIsClosed() == 1 || !$responce || $clientThread->isTerminated())
                                {
                                    unset($this->clients[$key]);
                                    $clientThread->kill();
                                }
                                echo 'RESPONCE is: ' . $responce . "\n";
                            }
                        }
                        echo 'Count of clients arr is: '. count($this->clients) . "\n";
                        $this->clients[$client_id] = new Client($client, $sock_id, $client_id);
                        $client_id++;

                    }
                    // Start The Threads
                    foreach ( $this->clients as $key=>$clientThread )
                    {
                        if( !$clientThread->isStarted())
                        {
                            $clientThread->start();
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

}
```

And my client class is:

```
class Client extends Thread {

    public $stop = false;
    public $Timeout = 4000;  //millisecounds
    public $CurrentTime = 0;
    public $CurrentTimeout = 0;
    public $isClosed; // 0 - false; 1 - true;
    public $isWorking = 1; // 0 - false; 1 - true;
    private $SocketPort = PORT_NUMBER;
    private $SOCK_ID;
    private $CLIENT_ID;

    function setIsClosed($isClosed)
    {
        $this->isClosed = $isClosed;
    }

    function getIsClosed()
    {
        return $this->isClosed;
    }

    function isThreadAlive()
    {
        return true;
    }

    public FUNCTION __construct($socket, $sock_id, $client_id)
    {
        $this->socket = $socket;
        $this->SOCK_ID = $sock_id;
        $this->CLIENT_ID = $client_id;
        $this->isClosed = 0;

        $this->start();
    }

    protected function __distruct()
    {
        gc_collect_cycles();
    }

    FUNCTION disconnect($client)
    {
        $this->socketWriteWithChr10($client, 'Successfuly Disconnected from Server.');

        $this->isClosed = 1;
        $this->stop = true;
        socket_shutdown($client, 2);
        socket_close($client);
        $this->__distruct();
   }

    public FUNCTION run()
    {
        $client = $this->socket;
        $this->connect($client);

        while ( true )
        {
            $command = socket_read($client, 2048) or $this->stop = true;

            if ( $command === false || $command == '' )
            {
                $this->socketWriteWithChr10($client, 'Nothing to read! Successfuly Disconnected from Server.');
                $this->stop = true;
                $this->isClosed = 1;
                socket_shutdown($client, 2);
                socket_close($client);
                break;
            }

            $this->getCommand($client, $command);
            if($this->stop)
            {
                break;
            }
        }

    }


    public FUNCTION getCommand($client, $input)
    {
        switch (trim($input))
        {
            case 'FILE':
                //Filename to save
                file_put_contents('../SOCKET_FILES/' . $ID . '/' . $Dirs . $FILENAME, fileContent);break;

            default :
                $this->socketWriteWithChr10($client, 'unknown command');
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

When i connect 1MB of is up and when i disconnect 1MB is reduce, but when i send files i get memory leaks. I can reduce memory when client is not connected, but if i send files the memory grow up and i have to restart my server.

The client program do this:

1. Connect
2. Send command file
3. Send parameters like ID,Dirs, ect.
4. The Server saves this file and send to client that file is written.
5. Client close the connection by command disconnect (server hit method disconnect).

The client program sends 6 files at once by while with 22 iterations.

In this steps memory grows and i can't reduce it. The strange fact is that i reduce my clients array.
What can it be? Im not good with linux. I only use htop.

I was googled and tried many examples, but the problem remains.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I found it. The problem is that 1 client try to send many files at once and the server can't close all files in time.